# How to fix runtime 9 in a subroutine - work or fails

Tags: excel, vba, printing

My stand-alone Workbook subroutines work for many calls, fails for these. This is the most simple example to reproduce the problem.

Manualy seting up the print page breaks provides the expected results. These subs work for many sheets, fail for two. Many columns are hidden - which keeps the printout within the printer's limits.

```
 this works

    BMPRangeSetup
    MyPageSetup
    DownPageBreaks
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate _
        :=True

this fails

    CMPRangeSetup
    MyPageSetup
    DownPageBreaks
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate _
        :=True

BMPRangeSetup contains:

    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$BH$210"

Where CMPRangeSetup has:

    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$BV$210"

the failure shows at Range("A111") 

    Sub DownPageBreaks()
      ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks
      ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location = Range("A61")
      ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(2).Location = Range("A111")
      ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(3).Location = Range("A161")
    End Sub
```

Comment: The error is quite clear - From Help **9 Subscript out of range** *The array you are trying to access contains fewer elements than you expect. For example, attempting to access the 11th element of an array dimensioned for ten elements.*

**To correct this error** 

 *Make sure your code contains bounds checking that ensures elements beyond the scope of the array are not referenced.* 
 *Re-dimension the array to a larger size that meets your needs.*

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa174230(v%3Doffice.11)

Comment: From a quick internet search - [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/210663/you-receive-a-subscript-out-of-range-error-message-when-you-use-hpageb) and [here](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/87344-subscript-out-of-range-for-hpagebreaks) - this seems potentially like a bug. It also sounds like `HPageBreaks.Count` is not 100% reliable. The first link has a possible solution which may need tweaking.

Comment: Thank you, @Noodles. The only problem is that I am not using any array (that I know of).
Based on your link, I have tried:
...
    ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks
    ActiveSheet.Range("A61").Select
    ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ActiveCell
    ....> 
...
and still get the failure.

Comment: You are using a collection and there is no 2nd hard page break to get the location of.

Comment: Notice the answer you accepted is adding them.

Comment: Thank you, @Noodles. I acknowledge my ignorance as I do not understand your "You are using a collection and there is no hard page break to get the location of." AcsErno 's suggestion of making sure that the active cell was outside the print range did work for me.

Comment: The message says that you are accessing an index that doesn't exist. That is a collection or an array or an object like it that you can index. The help message was written before collections existed. Basic is 55 years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BigBen is right, `.HPageBreaks` sometimes fails. Try this:

```
With ActiveSheet
     .ResetAllPageBreaks
     .HPageBreaks.Add Range("A61")
     .HPageBreaks.Add Range("A111")
     .HPageBreaks.Add Range("A161")
End With
```

It might also help to move ActiveCell out of the affected area before setting page breaks:

```
Dim sCell as String

sCell = ActiveCell.Address
Range("AA1111").Activate
....
Range(sCell).Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @AcsErno!
I find that this works!

```
 Range("A212").Activate     ' a cell outside print range.
 With ActiveSheet
     .ResetAllPageBreaks
     .HPageBreaks.Add Range("A61")
     .HPageBreaks.Add Range("A111")
     .HPageBreaks.Add Range("A161")
 End With
```